# Offset a Vlookup value in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to return a value which is one row below a specific cell in Excel. For example, it Vlookups for each name and I need to return the value for total activity.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
=offset(vlookup(A4,'Case Manager Reports - Jun'!A:B,2,0), 1, 0)
```

I know that Vlookups return just the value of the cell rather than the address so it makes sense that this formula doesn't work - is there any way valid way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with Index/Match+1, like so:

`=INDEX('Case Manager Reports - Jun'!B:B,MATCH(A4,'Case Manager Reports - Jun'!A:A,0)+1)`

Comment: Works great, how would this work if I wanted to offset column instead?

Comment: Change the column listed in the Index portion of the formula.  Right now it's pointed at column B.

Comment: (afaik) you may replace `'Case Manager Reports - Jun'!B:B` with `OFFSET('Case Manager Reports - Jun'!$B:$B,0,1)` inside that formula.